# fill surface between two objects and change color in gradient

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I have some material defined that changes the color of the object based on its z rotation (c.f. attached image)). Now I want to interpolate a surface (one of the surfaces is sketched in the image) between every two arrows and have the surface changing color in gradient between the colors of the two arrows.

Could you share your ideas in terms of how to create the surface and how to have the color changing correctly?

Something that I tried is to add a path following the direction of each arrow and then turn the path to mesh and then fill the surface between the vertices.

Manually made template of what I want:[image]

[image]

Comment: can you sketch where the surface is? Are the arrows parallel to the normal of the surface? Or is the surface lofting the arrows, where arrows are aligned with one axis of the plane?

Comment: By "a surface between every two arrows", do you mean a quad surface, with one edge connecting the arrow tips, one edge connecting the arrow heads, and the two remaining edges connecting tip to head for each arrow ?

Comment: @StefLAncien Yes, exactly

Comment: Do you want to do this in Object/Edit Mode or using Geometry Nodes ? Could you share your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: @StefLAncien, I just did, and I assume I need geometry nodes since I need to scale the operation to a large amount of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily we can isolate the arrows in a collection and these arrows are named in the good way so that they are ordered.

Due to that, we can map a grid on the arrows positions.

[image]

[image]

We take the arrow collection as input and sample:

- their position to place the grid over them
- their scale and rotation to store these attributes on the grid vertices

As we want vertical bands between two arrows, split the edges, delete horizontal edges. We now have the wanted values, but on a vertical line.

Extrude these lines to recreate the faces and adjust their positions so that they are centered to the arrows.

Set that the same material as the one you created for the arrows.

---

We can also have these gradient result:

[image]

by just keeping this part of the node tree:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

---

---

An update as you also want to rotate and scale the colored bands:

[image]

Capture the instance positions which will be the rotation centers.

Extrude zero (instead of 1 above).

Shift the top part of the extrusion accordingly to the scale.

Shift back all accordingly to the half of the scale.

Rotate around Z with the named att 'rotation'.

Eventually add a subdivision surface with crease in order to have a smoother rotation.

Result:

[image]

Updated file (4.0):

[image]

Comment: Glamorous solution!

Comment: Thanks so much, this will be valuable for a lot of other users I believe, but it is not exactly what I wanted. I made an edit to my post by uploading a template of what I wanted. I managed to get the surface by having paths along the arrows and then fill the surface between them. However, the problem I have now is, I don't know how to properly use the shade nodes so that the plane is a gradient color between the two arrows. Do you have any insights? –

Answer (score 1):

The following might work for you.  It uses a custom (type=color) property for each "arrow" (I used cones).   For each of these colors (arrow-a and arrow-b),

[image]

I use these to drive both the color node of it's Principled BSDF, and also a color driver for each of the two gradient colors:

[image]

I also had to play a bit with the mapping properties of the texture coordinate mappings:
[image]

My example: [image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this will be valuable for a lot of other users I believe, but it is not exactly what I wanted. I made an edit to my post by uploading a template of what I wanted. I managed to get the surface by having paths along the arrows and then fill the surface between them. However, the problem I have now is, I don't know how to properly use the shade nodes so that the plane is a gradient color between the two arrows. Do you have any insights?